# How to Traverse Files in React using fetch

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a reactjs application and I'm trying to pull json data from a file that is in a different folder than the index js or jsx file making the fetch call. However, I can't tell if the file is being pulled properly or at all. I also can't tell if my fetch function is called from my index.js or the .jsx file that its actually written in.

Folder Layout:

> Base Folder
>
> > index.js
> >
> > > src (folder)
> > > components
> > >
> > > > FactsApp.jsx (fetch call is here)

> > TestData (folder)
> >
> > > QuickFactsData.json(data I am trying to retrieve)

FactsApp.jsx:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import TitleBarApp from "./TitleBarApp";
    
    class FactsApp extends Component {
      state = {
        titleData: {
          titleName: "Quick Facts",
          SearchBool: true,
          SearchFunc: null,
        },
        displayData: {},
      };
    
      fetchFirst() {
        let that = this;
        fetch("/../TestData/QuickFactsData.json") //This is the fetch call in question
          .then(function (resp) {
            return resp;
          })
          .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            console.log(result.json());
          });
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchFirst();
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <TitleBarApp titleData={this.state.titleData}></TitleBarApp>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is import your JSON!

e.g:

```
import JSONDATA from "../../TestData/QuickFactsData";

console.log(JSONDATA.BlahBlah);
```

Comment: The issue is not simply getting the data but getting the data with 'fetch'. If I were to use any manner of API's, I'd have to use fetch and this program is a sort of draft for that.

Comment: @Chaospyke put your JSON files in the public folder... after that, you can fetch those files